# how to capture the content of the sentence except period?(period may not exist)

Tags: regex, regex-group

What I'm trying to do is: if `(.*)(\.)` doesn't match, then try to match `(.")` then capture the group.

Is there any way to write this in one regex? I tried `(.*)(\.?)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am negating the period character:
/[^.]+/gm

https://regex101.com/r/BP7WWQ/1

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
^[^.\n]+(?=\.$|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/grWjgJ/1)

Explanation :

`^` asserts position at start of a line.
`[^.\n]+` the sentence should not have `\n` and period.
`(?=\.$|$)` with help of positive lookahead assertion, check to see if there may or may not a period at the end.